# Vue Js - issue with axios Performing multiple concurrent requests with laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade, vue-component, vue.js

alright I have small issue may be but I can't figure it out.

if I pass only one http request using axios all work good.

but when I use multiple request I get result in console log but can't able to send  to view file ( laravel blade view file).

let me show you my code :

**brand.blade.php**

```
// main element for Vue js el: '#container'
<div id="container" class="row all_brands">
        <brands></brands>
    </div>


// template for brand component
<template id="brand-template">
   <ul>
     // if I only pass one http request through axios then  my data shows here but for multiple request not showing anything.
     <li v-for="brand in list" v-text="brand.brand_id"></li>

   </ul>
   @{{count}}
</template>
```

**brand.js**

```
Vue.component('brands',{

template: '#brand-template',

data: function(){

    return{

        list: [],
        count: ''
    }

},

created: function(){

    //axios.get('api/brands').then(response => this.list = response.data) ; // here I send only one gttp request and working find..

    axios.all([
    axios.get('api/brands'),
    axios.get('api/brand_count')
    ])
        .then(
        axios.spread(
            function (brand, count) {
             // this is not working and not set these data to my brand.blade.php file template
             this.list = brand.data;
             this.count = count.data;
             // console show me all the data that coming from http request  
            //console.log('list',brand.data);
            //console.log('count',count.data);
            }
    ))

}

});


new Vue({

el: '#container'

})
```

can any one let me how to show data in my view file ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because scope of `this` is not correct in `axios.spread`, earlier it was working for you, as you were using es6 arrow function, which automatically binds `this` scope.

You can make following changes to make it work:

```
created: function(){
    var that = this    
    axios.all([
    axios.get('api/brands'),
    axios.get('api/brand_count')
    ])
        .then(
        axios.spread(
            function (brand, count) {
             that.list = brand.data;
             that.count = count.data;
            }
    ))

}
```